# how to migrate and transform laravel 4 filters to laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to migrate from laravel 4 to laravel 5, and it seems filter concept has been changed in laravel 5.

I have the filter below (and also auth, guest, csrf filters) in app/filters.php file:

```
Route::filter('date_validation', function ($route, $request) {
    $parameters = $route->parameters();
    if(array_key_exists('date', $parameters)) {
        $date = $parameters["date"];            

        if(strtotime($date) > time() || strtotime($date) < strtotime('2014-01-01')) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }

    }

    if(array_key_exists('time', $parameters)) {
        $time = $parameters["time"];

        if($time > '23-59') {
            return Redirect::to('/den');
        }
    }

});
```

I have defined some routes in routes.php file using this filter like that:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'date_validation'), function() {
    // some routes.
});
```

But now, I see that I should use middleware. I think I should add filters to boot method of App\Providers\RouteServiceProviders class. But how? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware).

Create your middleware:
`php artisan make:middleware DateValidation`

Add it to Kernel:

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'date_validation' => \App\Http\Middleware\DateValidation::class,
];
```

In your middleware you could do something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $parameters = $request->route()->parameters();
    if(array_key_exists('date', $parameters)) {
       $date = $parameters["date"];            

        if(strtotime($date) > time() || strtotime($date) < strtotime('2014-01-01')) {
          return Redirect::to('/');
        }

    }

    if(array_key_exists('time', $parameters)) {
        $time = $parameters["time"];

        if($time > '23-59') {
            return Redirect::to('/den');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```